# Get number into string with regex

Tags: java, regex

I have to extract two number in a string, this is always like this:

```
file_Sig201701311539043872_1736587_614007_marketing.000
```

I need to save in different value :

- 1736587
- 614007

How i can do this ?

I tried with: `\_(.*?)\_` but not work properly.

Comment: `(?<=_)\\d+` seems to work just fine

Comment: Use [`^file_[^_]*_([0-9]+)_([0-9]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/j9iOqy/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following [pattern matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html):

```
  final Pattern NUMBER_MATCHER = Pattern.compile("_(\\d+)_(\\d+)");
  Matcher matcher = NUMBER_MATCHER.matcher(/* your file name */);
  if (matcher.find()) {
     System.out.println("matcher.group(1) = " + matcher.group(1));
     System.out.println("matcher.group(2) = " + matcher.group(2));
  }
```

which prints:

```
matcher.group(1) = 1736587
matcher.group(2) = 614007
```

For now the regex works for underscore followed by any number of digits followed by an underscore and then again any number of digits.

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage lookarounds:

```
(?<=_)(\\d+)(?=_)
```

The captured groups would contain the required digits.

- The zero width negative lookbehind, `(?<=_)` makes sure the match is preceded by a `_`
- The zero width negative lookbehind, `(?=_)` makes sure the match is followed by a `_`
- `(\d+)` matches one or more digits and put in captured group

Answer (score 1):

Try with this one. 
**Sample Code**

```
final Pattern NUMBER_MATCHER = Pattern.compile("_(\\d*)_(\\d*)");
        Matcher matcher =    NUMBER_MATCHER.matcher("file_Sig201701311539043872_1736587_614007_marketing.000");
        if (matcher.find()) {
             System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
           System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
        }
```